# Finding pattern in matrix inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, discrete-mathematics, pattern-recognition

I want to see if any pattern that could be formulated exist across the rows (or equivalently , columns) of the matrix inverse (in the middle , let's name it $A^{-1}$) so that an analytical  formula that relates $o_n$ and $b_n$ (perhaps along with other b's) exists (for any positive integer n )
$$
 \begin{pmatrix}
o_1 \\
o_2 \\
: \\
: \\
: \\
o_n 
\end{pmatrix} = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0  & 0 & ... & 0 \\
w & 1 & 0   & 0 & \ddots & 0  \\ 
i & w & 1  & 0 & \ddots & 0 \\ 
i & i & w & 1 & \ddots & 0 \\ 
: & \ddots & \ddots  & \ddots & \ddots  & \ddots \\ 
i & i & i & ... & w & 1 
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
b_1 \\
b_2 \\
: \\
: \\
: \\
b_n 
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
The matrix inverse $A^{-1}$ is a lower triangular matrix with diagonal full of 1 , subdiagonal full of w and others are i .

when $n = 6$ , the matrix inverse becomes
$$ \left( \begin{array}{cccccc} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -w & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ w^2-i & -w & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -w^3+2 i w-i & w^2-i & -w & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ w^4-3 i w^2+2 i w+i^2-i & -w^3+2 i w-i & w^2-i & -w & 1 & 0 \\ -w^5+4 i w^3-3 i w^2-3 i^2 w+2 i w+2 i^2-i & w^4-3 i w^2+2 i w+i^2-i & -w^3+2 i w-i & w^2-i & -w & 1 \end{array} \right) $$

I recommend matrix calculator https://www.dcode.fr/matrix-inverse to quickly find matrix inverse symbolically .

Since in this case it doesn't matter whether we look at rows or columns , by looking at the first column , I could only write down
$$  \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc}
a_1 & = & 1 \\
a_2 & = & a_1 (-w) \\
a_3 & = & a_2 (-w) - i  \\
a_4 & = & a_3 (-w) + iw - i\\
a_5 & = & a_4 (-w) + iw - iw^2 - i + i^2\\
a_6 & = & a_5 (-w) + iw - iw^2 +iw^3 - 2i^2w - i + 2i^2\\
\end{array} \right.
$$

**Edit : After reading @metamorphy 's answer**

Below is my note ,

since the "1"-diagonal of $S^k$ will lie on the $k^{th}$ subdiagonal , we may visualize $A^{-1}$ and write down
$$
o_n =  ( \alpha_+\lambda_{+}^0 + \alpha_- \lambda_{-}^{0} ) b_n + 
( \alpha_+\lambda_{+}^{1} + \alpha_- \lambda_{-}^{1} ) b_{n-1} + ... + 
( \alpha_+\lambda_{+}^{n-1} + \alpha_- \lambda_{-}^{n-1} ) b_{1} 
$$
$$
 = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} ( \alpha_+\lambda_{+}^{k} + \alpha_- \lambda_{-}^{k} ) b_{n-k} 
$$
with
$$ \alpha_+ = \frac{\lambda_{+} - 1 }{\lambda_{+} - \lambda_{-}} ,\qquad \alpha_- = \frac{\lambda_{-} - 1 }{\lambda_{-} - \lambda_{+}} 
$$

Comment: surely you should be able to derive a recurrence for these $a_i$'s just deriving from the fact that $A^{-1}A = I.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S$ be the $n\times n$ matrix with $S_{ij}=\begin{cases}1,&i=j+1\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

The matrix being inverted is $A=I+wS+iS^2(I-S)^{-1}$, hence $A^{-1}=f(S)$ with $$f(z)=\frac{1-z}{1-(1-w)z-(w-i)z^2}.$$

Next, we find the [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) of $f(z)$, say $$f(z)=\frac{\alpha_+}{1-\lambda_+ z}+\frac{\alpha_-}{1-\lambda_- z},\qquad\lambda_\pm=\frac12\left(1-w\pm\sqrt{(1+w)^2-4i}\right)$$ (this is possible if $(1+w)^2\neq4i$; use continuity or symbolic argument otherwise). Then $$A^{-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(\alpha_+\lambda_+^k+\alpha_-\lambda_-^k)S^k$$ because $S^k=0$ for $k\geqslant n$; this gives a closed form of the elements on $k$-th diagonals of $A^{-1}$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on the derivation of the final summation ? After obtaining $A^{-1} = f(S) = \frac{\alpha_+}{\mathbb{I} -\lambda_+ S} + \frac{\alpha_-}{\mathbb{I}-\lambda_- S} $ , what's next  ? did you apply any formula ?

Comment: @user897319: [$(I-N)^{-1}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix#Additional_properties) for a nilpotent $N$.

Comment: Actually I  I don't know matrices could be in the denominator , and the domain of f(z) seems to be within $\mathbb{R}^1$ , so I  don't really know how to make sense of f(S) .

Comment: @user897319: $\frac\alpha{1-\lambda S}$ means $\alpha(1-\lambda S)^{-1}$, and similarly $\frac{p(S)}{q(S)}=p(S)[q(S)]^{-1}=[q(S)]^{-1}p(S)$ for polynomials $p,q$; these matrices in fact commute. (The language is from [these concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function_of_a_matrix), not really needed here - just to simplify the notation).

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on "use continuity or symbolic argument otherwise" , does it mean we still need to carry out partial decomposition and write in this form : $\frac{\alpha_+}{1-\lambda_+z} +\frac{\alpha_-}{1-\lambda_-z}  $ ? because otherwise we cannot use the nilpotent matrix property to derive the final expression

Comment: @user897319: If $(1+w)^2=4i$ then $\lambda_+=\lambda_-$, and $f(z)=(1-z)/(1-\lambda z)^2$ is not "a geometric series" anymore. One could still use its power series; another way (the "continuity" argument) is that everything is continuous w.r.t. $w$, and we can take a limit. E.g. our coefficients are $\alpha_+\lambda_+^k+\alpha_-\lambda_-^k=c_{k+1}-c_k$ where $c_k=(\lambda_+^k-\lambda_-^k)/(\lambda_+-\lambda_-)$ have a limit $k\lambda^{k-1}$ as $\lambda_\pm\to\lambda$.

Comment: I used a calculator and found  the roots of the polynomial are $ \frac{1}{2(i-w)}(1-w \pm \sqrt{(w+1)^2 - 4i} ) $ , then should $\lambda_{\pm}$ be $\frac{1}{root} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2(i-w)}(1-w \pm \sqrt{(w+1)^2 - 4i} )}$ ? Because when we plug in root the expression should be 1-1=0  , but that don't match your $\lambda_{\pm}$ , am I missing something ?

Comment: I tried to generalize you idea  , the $n\times n$ matrix being inverted is $M=I+w\sum_{k=1}^{p} S^k+iS^{p+1} (I-S)^{-1}$ for positive integer p . Suppose there're j roots , so $M^{-1}=(I-S) (I - [ (1 -w)S + (w-i)S^{p+1} ])^{-1} = (I-S) \left( \prod_{i=1}^j (I - \lambda_i S) \right)^{-1} $ $=  \sum_{i=1}^j \alpha_i \left(I - \lambda_i S \right)^{-1} =  \sum_{i=1}^j \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \alpha_i  \lambda_i^k S^k $ , is it correct ? could there be more simplification ?

Comment: 1) Our $\lambda_\pm$ match, please check carefully. 2) Yes, $(I-N)^{-1}$ can be used without partial fractions (this was my approach in a prior answer, now deleted), and this gives a polynomial representation (no radicals here), but with summation signs that can't be avoided.